# Zabbix user login trigger

Tags: authentication, ssh, zabbix

I have a problem with zabbix, i want him to search trough /var/log/log.auth and send a notification when someone logs into by SSH. I know how to send notifications when trigger is active but i don't know how to create this exact trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set up a log item like `log[/var/log/log.auth,authentication successful]` (or the exact string you are looking for in the logfile.

Then you should create a corresponding trigger with the regexp function: `.regexp(authentication successful)}=1`

From the doc, regexp:

> Returns:
>
> 1 - found
>
> 0 - otherwise

It's a bit redundant, but it's good to filter out everything you don't need before storing it into zabbix.